# Error while changing the encoding of a String with python. UTF-8 & cp1252

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I need to convert a string so as to convert it into human readable format.

```
s = "that’s awful, Find â€“ Best Quotes, “Music gives a soul to the universe, wings to the mind, flight to the imagination and life to everything.” ― Plato."
```

I want to convert this string to `"that’s awful, Find - Best Quotes, "Music gives a soul to the universe, wings to the mind, flight to the imagination and life to everything." ― Plato."`

But I'm facing multiple issue w.r.t. different scenarios.

1. when I use `print(str(s.encode('cp1252',"ignore"),'utf-8'))`
   I get

   > UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 4
2. when I use `print(str(s.encode('cp1252'),'utf-8',"ignore"))`
   I get

   > UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2015' in position 151
3. when I use `print(str(s.encode('cp1252',"ignore"),'utf-8',"ignore"))`
   Then as can be predicted I get the string without error after omitting all apostrophe, single and double inverted commas as

   > "thats awful, Find – Best Quotes, Music gives a soul to the universe, wings to the mind, flight to the imagination and life to everything.  Plato."

Comment: So the 3rd case is working. It seems that ignoring the error in conversions helps raise no errors and the string converts. Also there was a typo is case 3, it was `s.encode` instead of `string.encode`

Comment: But I don't want to loose apostrophe, single and double inverted commas. So basically ignoring the error wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried everything but I could not fix it by myself. A simpler way to do the same search that you did is to s.encode('utf-8', "ignore").decode("utf-8", ignore). I tried latin1, ascii, cp1252 and utf8, utf16 in combinations and gave up.
I tried the encodings one by one from [this list](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html) of python encodings. Then I looked for code that could detect the same smarter.

Then I came by [a blog post](http://blog.conceptnet.io/posts/2012/fixing-common-unicode-mistakes-with-python-after-theyve-been-made/) which explains all the things that could go wrong in fixing the encoding. The solution they proposed was to **run a full search of all encodings to find the correct one.**

This package is called ftfy.

Disclaimer: I am not related to ftfy. I just saw it today.

> pip install ftfy

```
s = "that’s awful, Find â€“ Best Quotes, “Music gives a soul to the universe, wings to the mind, flight to the imagination and life to everything.” ― Plato."

import ftfy

print(ftfy.fix_text(s))
```

> that's awful, Find – Best Quotes, "Music gives a soul to the universe,
>   wings to the mind, flight to the imagination and life to everything."
>   ― Plato.

This solves the problem.
For more info on how they fixed it, see the source code of ftfy [here](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-ftfy) or docs [here](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#ftfy.fix_text). :)

Comment: glad to know it worked on performance/scale side, how big was the data set and how many seconds?

Comment: I processed a data set of 200k characters in about 2-3 seconds. It was actually a csv.